Getting a user ID in a single signal
I don't understand how to get the playerid of a specific user in the ios app in the latest version of One Signal.
My task is to get a specific id of the user in order to send notifications specifically to him.
How to do it? or is the logic not like that?
import UIKit
import OneSignalFramework
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                     [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE)

        OneSignal.initialize("------",
                             withLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

        OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission({ accepted in
            print("The user has accepted the notifications: \(accepted)")
        }, fallbackToSettings: true)

        return true
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                                @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                                @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}


Why dont you use OneSignal ID , check: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/users
